# How to get "always" permission of location for flutter in android 10 or above? (above API 29)?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, android-permissions, android-location

I am using Geolocator package for one of my flutter project, and I want to get my current location in periodic cycle of time.
To get the permission, I edited AndroidManifest.xml and added those line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

All things are working just fine, but when I use the apk in one of android 10 phone, everything go south!
First of all whenever I am checking the status of permission for the first time of app using

```
 await Geolocator.checkPermission();
```

It returns `.denied` in android 9, and `.deniedForever` in android 10, and when to check permission, the android permission seeking popup raised, in android 9 or bellow, the allow button set the permission to the `.always` but in android 10, is set to `.whileInUse` and I cannot find any option in setting to set it to `.always` manually.
After some research, I learn that, I have to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

I added them, but still android 10 does not act like android 9, still the "always" option in app manager are missing!
The main problem I am encountering is , whenever I off the screen, the `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition()` just stopped working but the same code works perfectly in android 9.

Simulation -

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List _loc = [];
  bool _isSwitchon = false;
  int _sec = 0;
  String _permissonStatus = "";

  Future _incrementCounter() async {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
      setState(() {
        _sec++;
      });
      if (_isSwitchon == false) {
        timer.cancel();
        setState(() {});
      } else if (_isSwitchon == true) {
        Position currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
        setState(() {
          _loc.add(currentPosition.toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Time Elapsed"),
            Text(_sec.toString() + "  sec"),
            Text(
              'current Location',
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _loc.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                  return Text(
                    _loc[i],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isSwitchon = true;
                        });
                        _incrementCounter();
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    ),
                    Text("Start")
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isSwitchon = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    ),
                    Text("Stop")
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(_permissonStatus),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Geolocator.checkPermission().then((value) =>
                            setState(
                                () => _permissonStatus = value.toString()));
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons
                          .signal_wifi_statusbar_connected_no_internet_4_sharp),
                    ),
                    Text("status")
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _loc = [];
                        });
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                    Text("clear Location")
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Geolocator.requestPermission();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
                    ),
                    Text("Permission Seeking")
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Scenario in my manifest -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gps_test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/> 
   <application
```

Answer (score 4):

You were talking about android 10, I dont see why there is not the right button, but to be future proof this method is outdated anyways.

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions?hl=fr):

> On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, however, the system dialog
> doesn't include the Allow all the time option. Instead, users must
> enable background location on a settings page, [...].

You should be able to open the permission settings with this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings), either via `.openLocationSettings()` or `.openAppSettings()` and then the user has to navigate to permissions.